# Reading columnar text data files in Node.js

Tags: node.js, parsing, text, fixed-width

I am looking for a Node.js package that can parse text data files. The files are not delimited, but instead have the data running in columns. What is this type of file called?

```
 Block   On  Off Miles 
  3001  250  279 1101.7
  3001  182  195  730.7
```

I can manually count columns and parse it myself, but there must be a better way.

Comment: They appear to be called fixed-width files. I still have not found a parser that will find the spaces automatically, so I am writing my own.

Answer (score 0):

This module seems to be the most popular for fixed-width files parsing `Fixy`.

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fixy

Sample code:

```
var fixy = fixy.parse({
map:[{
    name: "Age",
    width: 2,
    start: 1,
    type: "int"
  },{
    name: "Initial",
    width: 3,
    start: 3,
    type: "string"
  }],
  options:{
    fullwidth: 5,
    skiplines: null,
    format: "csv"
  }
}, "21ABC\n22DEF");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use `Typescript` and like `decorator`, you can try this
https://github.com/vcfvct/fixed-width-ts-decorator

> npm i fixed-width-ts-decorator

So the domain class and spec(width/start) can stay together. No separate schema creation is needed.

Example:

```js
export class Transaction extends FixedWidthConvertible {
  @FixedWidth({ start: 0, width: 5 })
  clientId: string;

  @FixedWidth({ start: 5, width: 40 })
  parentName: string;

  @FixedWidth({ start: 45, width: 40 })
  receiverId: string;

  @FixedWidth({ start: 85, width: 40 })
  paymentStatus: string;

  @FixedWidth({ start: 125, width: 20 })
  paymentTimeStamp: string;

  @FixedWidth({ start: 145, width: 40 })
  userId: string;

  @FixedWidth({ start: 225, width: 40 })
  paymentId: string;
  // other non-decorated fields
  otherField: string;
}
```